# Cannot Populate listView with ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>>

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist

---

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>  list;
f(!list.isEmpty()){

          adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.inner_base_header_cutom, list);
          listview.setAdapter(adapter);
          Log.i("LIST Active", "LIST Active" + list.size());
      }
```

---

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>> {
          private final Context context;
          private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> values;

          public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int innerBaseHeaderCutom, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> list) {
            super(context, innerBaseHeaderCutom, list);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = list;
          }
```

}

---

ERROR:

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>>(Context, int, ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>) is undefined
```

Also Cannot Remove ListView:

```
remove(list.get(position));
```

Error:

```
The method remove(ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>) in the type ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>> is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,capture#2-of ?>)
```

Comment: What is list in your code?

Comment: ` ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>`, I added some does above.

Comment: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>  list` why the `?`. They value is not a string?. Also where do you populate the list

Comment: Maybe try using `List` instead `ArrayList` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just strip the last argument when you call the constructor of the super class

```
super(context, innerBaseHeaderCutom);
```

---

EDIT:
Another think you can try is changing this:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>> {
```

for

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, ?>> {
```

And do the same change in the constructor.

Comment: how will the adapter know many list should be populated sir. still not populating I check the `list.size` and I got three.

Comment: Because the ArrayAdpater expects you to pass the type of objects that you will have in your **Array**, not the structure holding those objects (which is the ArrayList).

Answer (score 0):

```
You are creating ArrayList with ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> instead you can try ArrayList<HashMap<String, ? extends Object>>
```

Check the sample code and output.

```
public class MyJavaTesting{
public MyJavaTesting(ArrayList<HashMap<String, ? extends Object>> list) {
    System.out.println(list);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, ? extends Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("Key", "value");
    list.add(map1);

    HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map2.put("Key", new Object());
    list.add(map2);

    MyJavaTesting manager = new MyJavaTesting(list);
}
}
```

**Output:**
    [{Key=value}, {Key=java.lang.Object@4f1d0d}]